# Setting isTranslucent to false on tabBar makes my bottom button disappear

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I have the following simple case:

A `UINavigationController`, with a root view controller which contains a `tableView` spanning the whole view, and then a `button` at the bottom of the screen. I create the button like that:

```
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.height - 50, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 50))
self.view.addSubview(button)
```

This works fine, until I do the following:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
```

This will make my button created disappear. Can someone explain to me the reason for that? And how to fix that? Here is a screenshot of my simple case. The button at the bottom disappears.

Edit: For context: I am using [Eureka](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka) library for setting up my forms in the `tableView`, and wanted to add a sticky button at the bottom.

[image]

Comment: best way to test use some more value like CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.height - **150**, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 50)) so you might be get an idea what happens it is

Comment: @NitinGohel Thanks! The button did indeed appear :) I checked the documentation if the `isTranslucent` does something to the layout, but there is nothing mentioned there. Do you have any clue why my button is getting shifted?

Comment: see if we use isTranslucent = true then the view calculate y position from top under the navigation bar as a 0. and if we make it false then self.view's Y position calculated from navigation end after 55 px left. so that's why that shifted. and i suggest to do add button from storyboard with bottom constraint that will easy to take care about it instead of add programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up the `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` property of your `UIViewController` to `false`.

You can also take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20892650/3844242).

Comment: I just edited my answer with a link that might be helpful for you.

Comment: @StefanStefanov automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets its related to UIScollView and subclass of Scrollview. UIviewController is not a subclass of UIScrollview so that wont effect at all. if in side UIViewController User used UIScrollview, UITableview, UICollectionView or any other object that subclass of UIScrollview then that will helps

Comment: Okay, first of all why does your `UITableView` have the frame of your whole screen since you want a `UIButton` underneath it? Maybe this is causing the problem. You can instantiate your button first and then constrain the tableView.bottom to the button.top.

Comment: I am using the Eureka library (as mentioned in my Edit), so they are taking care of creating the tableView behind the scene. That's why I got into this situation. But I do have access to the tableView, so I guess I can change the constraints for it, and add the button below it