# UISearchController shifted up when typing under UINavigationController

Tags: swift, xcode

I embedded a viewcontroller(BlueViewController) in a navigation controller.

the blueViewController has a UISearchController that set as the blueViewController's tableView headerView.

the searchController works fine except when it's active, it shift up and hide behind the UINavigationController(or somewhere)

I've tried to add the search controller's searchBar as a subview to the viewController, or positions a UIView and assigned the searchBar to that UIView, none of these works

I have tried this link, doesn't work
[Strange UISearchDisplayController view offset behavior in iOS 7 when embedded in navigation bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731360/strange-uisearchdisplaycontroller-view-offset-behavior-in-ios-7-when-embedded-in)

here is the searchController in BlueViewController

```
let searchController:UISearchController = {
    let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    controller.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    controller.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    controller.searchBar.inputAssistantItem.leadingBarButtonGroups = []
    controller.searchBar.inputAssistantItem.trailingBarButtonGroups = []
    return controller
}()
```

In viewDidLoad

```
 searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    definesPresentationContext = true
```

you can also find entire project here
https://github.com/QiquanLu/TestNavigationWithSearchController

Any hint would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 11 and above, you should be setting the `searchController` property on `BlueViewController`'s navigationItem like so:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
}
```

Don't add it as the tableView's header.

Comment: Thanks, but the navigation items just not a place I want the  search bar to be.

Comment: Ah, I see. Not using the search controller this way might end up with weird bugs like the one you're seeing. Sorry I couldn't be of more help!